# TestNG, Surefire Configuration methods included in total number of tests

Tags: maven, selenium, jenkins, testng, surefire

I am using TestNG version 6.8.5 and Surefire maven plugin to drive my Selenium tests.

Whenever any configuration method fails in a test class, the test is skipped (which is expected.)

But the problem is - Total number of tests reported in result xml include the number of failed configuration methods.

I actually have 10 tests out of which 6 failed, 3 skipped (due to configuration failure) and 1 passed. But results xml shows wrongly as below.

```
<testsuite failures="9" time="224.726" errors="0" skipped="3" tests="13" name="TestSuite">
```

This creates confusion in email and Jenkins notifications. Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Did you find any solution ? I'm experiencing the same issue